# PHP MYSQL validate variable is of database type

Tags: php, mysql, validation, types

I am working on a validation routine. The validation needs to be able to take a variable and a mysql data type and return true if the variable is valid for the given mysql data type.

Example

```
$price = 1000

$type = "datetime"
```

This should return false

```
$price = 789

$type = "int(11)"
```

This should return true.

My initial plan is to query the database using DESCRIBE [TABLE] for a selected table and retrieve it's fields along with their data type.

e.g

```
Code | char(9)
Name |text
Age  |int
```

Then I want to validate values from a json string and ensure the parsed data is valid for the given table.

```
Code: ONE12345

Name: Jimmy1

Age: fifty
```

Any help would be appreciated! thanks in advance.

Comment: My approach would be using a try ..catch and throwing an exception. You may either get the data types from the db or define your self. Again there are numerous amounts of php validation classes on the internet. unless you're brave enough to write your own. this would be fun

Comment: Could you recommend a validation class that maybe able to help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a google search so many PHP validation classes should show up. Do some research on selecting the best for your needs :)

or you could write your own. This is something i wrote years ago.

```
function validateInputs($fields){
        foreach ($fields as $field => $fieldInfo){
            foreach (explode(',', $fieldInfo[1]) as $ruleString) {

                $ruleOp = explode('|', $fieldInfo[1]);
                $rule = $ruleOp[0];
                $op = isset($ruleOp[1]) ? $ruleOp[1] : '';
                $val = isset($ruleOp[2]) ? $ruleOp[2] : false;

                switch ($rule) {
                    case 'required':
                        if(!isset($_POST[$field] || (isset($_POST[$field] && $_POST[$field] == '')){
                            throw new Exception ($fieldInfo[0].' is required');
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'requiredif':
                        if(!isset($_POST[$op] || (isset($_POST[$op] && $_POST[$op] == '')
                        && !isset($_POST[$field] || (isset($_POST[$field] && $_POST[$field] == '' && $val ==     false)
                        || ($val !== false && isset($_POST[$op] && $_POST[$op] === $val && isset($_POST[$op]     && $_POST[$op] == '')){
                            throw new Exception ($fieldInfo[0].' needs a value');
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'email':
                        if(isset($_POST[$field] && !filter_var($_POST[$field], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                            throw new Exception ($fieldInfo[0].' is not a valid email');
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'match':
                        if(isset($_POST[$field] && isset($_POST[$op] 
                            && $_POST[$field] != $_POST[$op]){
                            throw new Exception ($fieldInfo[0].' should match with `'.$fields[$op][0].'`');
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'file':
                        if(isset($_POST[$field] && !$_POST[$field] instanceof stdClass){
                            throw new Exception ($fieldInfo[0].' is not a valid file');
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how i call it.

```
try{
    validateInputs(array(
        'name' => array('Username', 'required'),
        'email' => array('Email', 'required|email')
    ));
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```